# preventing the default form submit event from firing if javascript is anabled using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form on a page.  Inside it I have an  element. If javascript is on, I want to disable the submit event.  And handle the action in MyMethod using Ajax.  How do I prevent the submit event from firing?

I believe something of the form: event.preventDefault() would do the trick. But I cant figure out how to pass in the event.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could subscribe to the [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event of the form and return false from it:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        // TODO: do your AJAX stuff here
        // for example ajaxify the form
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
                // TODO: process the result of your AJAX request
            }
        });

        // this is what will cancel the default action
        return false;
    });
});
```

or:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();

        // TODO: do your AJAX stuff here
        // for example ajaxify the form
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
                // TODO: process the result of your AJAX request
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! And thanks for adding the first version. While the answe to my question is the second version, the first version is better and what I actually implemented.